# Flutter: get parent navigator when route does not exists on current navigator

Tags: flutter, navigation

How we can get parent navigator when route does not exists on current navigator?

**Maybe useful tips**

`onGenerateRoute` and `onUnknownRoute` maybe useful but both of them have to return a route, if not they through exception.

```
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/home':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen());
      case '/verify':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => VerifyScreen());
      default:
        // route not found, so get the parent navigator and push requested route on that
    }
  },

  onUnknownRoute: (settings) {
    // route not found, so get the parent navigator and push requested route on that
  },
```

of course with `rootNavigator=true` we can get the root navigator and not parent navigator in the nested scenarios.

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator=true)
```

Thnx